# How to use LayoutBuilder without intrinsic dimensions?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to achieve the following layout:

[image]

Here's the code I'm currently working on:

```dart
class TimelineList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              _Timeline(hasUpperConnection: false, hasLowerConnection: true),
              const SizedBox(width: 24),
              Expanded(child: _LayoutBuilderWidget()),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              _Timeline(hasUpperConnection: true, hasLowerConnection: true),
              const SizedBox(width: 24),
              Expanded(child: _LayoutBuilderWidget()),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              _Timeline(hasUpperConnection: true, hasLowerConnection: false),
              const SizedBox(width: 24),
              Expanded(child: _LayoutBuilderWidget()),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _LayoutBuilderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const _LayoutBuilderWidget();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, size) {
        return Text('This widget is ${size.maxWidth} pixels wide.');
      },
    );
  }
}

class _Timeline extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Timeline({this.hasUpperConnection = false, this.hasLowerConnection = false});

  final bool hasUpperConnection;
  final bool hasLowerConnection;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 26,
          child: VerticalDivider(
            color: hasUpperConnection ? AppColors.forest : Colors.transparent,
            thickness: 2,
            width: 2,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 10,
          height: 10,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: hasUpperConnection && hasLowerConnection ? Colors.transparent : AppColors.forest,
            border: Border.all(color: AppColors.forest, width: 2),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: VerticalDivider(
            color: hasLowerConnection ? AppColors.forest : Colors.transparent,
            thickness: 2,
            width: 2,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is:

`Unhandled Exception: LayoutBuilder does not support returning intrinsic dimensions. Calculating the intrinsic dimensions would require running the layout callback speculatively, which might mutate the live render object tree`

Which makes sense, since the `_LayoutBuilderWidget` widget cannot define its intrinsic dimensions.

The original layout is more complex than this one, and I need to use `LayoutBuilder` to know how much horizontal space I have to build the content in the right side of the timeline.

Also, not sure if the `IntrinsicHeight` widget is necessary, and I would like to avoid using it since its usage is expensive.

Added some background colors to the texts in the right side to indicate that the height its dynamic based on the content.

Is it possible to indicate to the `LayoutBuilder` widget its dimensions without specifying a fixed height for any of the components, since the content height is dynamic?

Comment: is there anything preventing you from placing LayoutBuilder one level higher in the hierarchy? above the IntrinsicHeight?

Comment: Placing it above the `IntrinsicHeight` would give me a different layout size